¿cómo puedo hacer que un LabelFrame que contiene un Frame Canvas se pueda expandir junto con la ventana raíz?
def abrir_ventana_matriz():
global ventana_matriz, codigo_del_concepto, nombre_de_concepto, caja_de_lista_de_materiales, unidades_del_concepto
global texbox_codigos, texbox_Materiales, texbox_unidades, texbox_costos, combos_operaciones, texbox_cantidades, texbox_importes
global texbox_importe_letra, texbox_Nombre_analista, texbox_costo_directo, texbox_costo_indirecto, texbox_precio_unitario
global label_porcentaje_costo_indirecto, texbox_porcentaje_costo_indirecto

ventana_matriz = tk.Tk()
ventana_matriz.title("Matriz de precios")
ventana_matriz.geometry("1200x720")

ventana_matriz.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
ventana_matriz.rowconfigure(1, weight=4)
ventana_matriz.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

ventana_matriz.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
ventana_matriz.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

##################################################################################################################################################
grupo_de_datos_generales = ttk.LabelFrame(ventana_matriz, text="Clave, Concepto, Unidades")
grupo_de_datos_generales.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

grupo_de_datos_generales.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
grupo_de_datos_generales.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

grupo_de_datos_generales.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
grupo_de_datos_generales.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
grupo_de_datos_generales.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

codigo_del_concepto = ttk.Entry(grupo_de_datos_generales)
codigo_del_concepto.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)

nombre_de_concepto = ttk.Entry(grupo_de_datos_generales)
nombre_de_concepto.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.E + tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
#nombre_de_concepto.bind("<Return>", matriz.enter_cencepto)

unidades_del_concepto = ttk.Entry(grupo_de_datos_generales)
unidades_del_concepto.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.E + tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

caja_de_lista_de_materiales = tk.Text(grupo_de_datos_generales, width=10, height=10)
caja_de_lista_de_materiales.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, padx=5, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W, columnspan=3)

##################################################################################################################################################

# Canvas y Scrollbar para grupo_de_precio__unitario
canvas_frame = tk.Frame(ventana_matriz)
canvas_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

canvas_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
canvas_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas = tk.Canvas(canvas_frame)
scrollbar_vertical = ttk.Scrollbar(canvas_frame, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar_horizontal = ttk.Scrollbar(canvas_frame, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)

scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)

scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_vertical.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbar_horizontal.set)

canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
scrollbar_vertical.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
scrollbar_horizontal.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

grupo_de_precio__unitario = ttk.LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text="Precio unitario")
grupo_de_precio__unitario.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

for x in range(7):
    grupo_de_precio__unitario.columnconfigure(x, weight=1)

for x in range(41):
    grupo_de_precio__unitario.rowconfigure(x, weight=1)

Label_codigo = ttk.Label(grupo_de_precio__unitario, width=15, text="codigos", anchor=tk.CENTER)
Label_Material = ttk.Label(grupo_de_precio__unitario, width=85, text="Materiales", anchor=tk.CENTER)
Label_unidades = ttk.Label(grupo_de_precio__unitario, width=12, text="Unidades", anchor=tk.CENTER)
Label_costo = ttk.Label(grupo_de_precio__unitario, width=15, text="Costo", anchor=tk.CENTER)
Label_operaciones = ttk.Label(grupo_de_precio__unitario, width=15, text="Operaciones", anchor=tk.CENTER)
Label_cantidad = ttk.Label(grupo_de_precio__unitario, width=15, text="Cantidad", anchor=tk.CENTER)
Label_importe = ttk.Label(grupo_de_precio__unitario, width=15, text="Importe", anchor=tk.CENTER)

Label_codigo.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
Label_Material.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
Label_unidades.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
Label_costo.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
Label_operaciones.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
Label_cantidad.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
Label_importe.grid(row=0, column=6, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)

texbox_codigos = []

for x in range(40):
    texbox_codigo = ttk.Entry(grupo_de_precio__unitario, width=15)
    texbox_codigo.grid(row=x + 1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
    texbox_codigos.append(texbox_codigo)

texbox_Materiales = []

for x in range(40):
    texbox_Materiale = ttk.Entry(grupo_de_precio__unitario, width=85)
    texbox_Materiale.grid(row=x + 1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
    texbox_Materiales.append(texbox_Materiale)

texbox_unidades = []

for x in range(40):
    texbox_unidad = ttk.Entry(grupo_de_precio__unitario, width=12)
    texbox_unidad.grid(row=x + 1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
    texbox_unidades.append(texbox_unidad)

texbox_costos = []

for x in range(40):
    texbox_costo = ttk.Entry(grupo_de_precio__unitario, width=15)
    texbox_costo.grid(row=x + 1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
    texbox_costos.append(texbox_costo)

combos_operaciones = []

for x in range(40):
    combo_operacion = ttk.Combobox(grupo_de_precio__unitario, width=15, values=["+", "-", "*", "/", "Elegir operación"], state="readonly")
    combo_operacion.grid(row=x + 1, column=4, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
    combo_operacion.set("Elegir operación")
    combos_operaciones.append(combo_operacion)

texbox_cantidades = []

for x in range(40):
    texbox_cantidad = ttk.Entry(grupo_de_precio__unitario, width=15)
    texbox_cantidad.grid(row=x + 1, column=5, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
    texbox_cantidades.append(texbox_cantidad)

texbox_importes = []

for x in range(40):
    texbox_importe = ttk.Entry(grupo_de_precio__unitario, width=15)
    texbox_importe.grid(row=x + 1, column=6, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
    texbox_importes.append(texbox_importe)

##################################################################################################################################################

grupo_costos_importes = ttk.LabelFrame(ventana_matriz, text="Costos e importes")
grupo_costos_importes.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

grupo_costos_importes.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
grupo_costos_importes.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
grupo_costos_importes.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
grupo_costos_importes.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

grupo_costos_importes.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
grupo_costos_importes.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
grupo_costos_importes.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

label_costo_Importe = ttk.Label(grupo_costos_importes, text="Importe")
label_costo_directo = ttk.Label(grupo_costos_importes, text="Costo directo")
label_costo_indirecto = ttk.Label(grupo_costos_importes, text="Costo indirecto")
label_costo_precio_unitario = ttk.Label(grupo_costos_importes, text="Precio unitario")
label_Nombre_del_analista = ttk.Label(grupo_costos_importes, text="Analista")
label_porcentaje_costo_indirecto = ttk.Label(grupo_costos_importes, text="porcentaje")

label_costo_Importe.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
label_Nombre_del_analista.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
label_costo_directo.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
label_costo_indirecto.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
label_costo_precio_unitario.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
label_porcentaje_costo_indirecto.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, padx=5, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)

texbox_importe_letra = ttk.Entry(grupo_costos_importes, width=40)
texbox_Nombre_analista = ttk.Entry(grupo_costos_importes, width=40)
texbox_costo_directo = ttk.Entry(grupo_costos_importes, width=15)
texbox_costo_indirecto = ttk.Entry(grupo_costos_importes, width=15)
texbox_precio_unitario = ttk.Entry(grupo_costos_importes, width=15)
texbox_porcentaje_costo_indirecto = ttk.Entry(grupo_costos_importes, width=40)

texbox_importe_letra.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
texbox_Nombre_analista.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
texbox_costo_directo.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
texbox_costo_indirecto.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
texbox_precio_unitario.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
texbox_porcentaje_costo_indirecto.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=5, pady=5)

##################################################################################################################################################

grupo_de_botones = ttk.LabelFrame(ventana_matriz, text="Opciones")
grupo_de_botones.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

grupo_de_botones.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
grupo_de_botones.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

grupo_de_botones.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
grupo_de_botones.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

boton_regresar = ttk.Button(grupo_de_botones, text="Regresar", width=40)
boton_guardar = ttk.Button(grupo_de_botones, text="Generar importes", width=40)
boton_Limpiar = ttk.Button(grupo_de_botones, text="Limpiar", width=40)
boton_Buscar = ttk.Button(grupo_de_botones, text="Crear PDF", width=40)

boton_regresar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
boton_guardar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
boton_Limpiar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
boton_Buscar.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

ventana_matriz.mainloop()

Todos los widgets que tengo fuera del LabelFrame "grupo_de_precio__unitario" se expanden correctamente pero en esta versión del código el propio widgent "grupo_de_precio__unitario" se queda fijo, a pesar que le indiqué en el grid(sticky=N+S+E+W). Tengo otra versión de esta ventana donde el LabelFrame si se expande, pero los elementos dentro del mismo (Entrys y Labels) se mantienden fijos con su tamaño ¿Existe alguna forma de modificar este código para que todo expanda correctamente con la ventana raíz (ventana_matriz)?
Agrego imágenes del comportamiento de ambas versiones del código


